# Unusual behavior of ggplot2 0.9.3

Tags: r, ggplot2

This code does not work as expected with `ggplot2 0.9.3` (worked fine with earlier versions of ggplot2, See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7324644/707145)). Is there a work-around for this problem?

```
library(ggplot2)
p <- qplot(as.factor(dose), len, data=ToothGrowth, geom = "boxplot", color = supp) + theme_bw()
p <- p + labs(x="Dose", y="Response")
p <- p + stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom = "point", color = "blue", aes(group=supp))
p <- p + stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom = "line", aes(group = supp))
p <- p  + theme(axis.title.x = element_text(size = 12, hjust = 0.54, vjust = 0))
p <- p  + theme(axis.title.y = element_text(size = 12, angle = 90,  vjust = 0.25))
print(p)
```

### Edit

This line

```
p <- p + stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom = "line", aes(group = supp))
```

produces the following warning

> geom_path: Each group consist of only one observation. Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?

Comment: I think you ought to print some intermediate steps AND SAY WHAT THE PROBLEM IS?

Comment: @DWin: Please see my edits. Thanks for showing your interest in my problem.

Comment: Can you explain what is not clear in the warning? Each group consists of only one value and you are plotting the mean of this value, which doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Roland: But the same code worked for ggplot2 0.9.2.

Comment: is there a chance that just the *warning* is new? else sample data might be useful... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: A warning is not an error.

Comment: The solution given by @joran on your previous post about this problem works also on ggplot2 0.9.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behavior is a bug in ggplot2 0.9.3: https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues/739

You can work around it by calculating the summaries using ddply:

```
library(plyr)
tg <- ddply(ToothGrowth, c("dose", "supp"), summarise, len = mean(len))

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(ToothGrowth, aes(x=as.factor(dose), y=len, colour=supp)) +
    geom_boxplot() +
    geom_line(data=tg, aes(group=supp))
```