# Creating interaction effect plot, ggplot or other

Tags: r, ggplot2, linear-regression

I have found an interaction effect between the predictors age and education level in a multiple regression model assessing the effects of various predictors on alcohol consumption. I wish to graph this interaction effect using ggplot, but an alternative will do.

I have attempted to do it this way:

```
p <- ggplot(DataFrame, aes(ED,AGE, label=interaction-effect))

p <- p + geom_point(colour= "red")+geom_text(size=3) # colour = colr does not work 

p
```

This is continuously spouting errors. I cannot seem to find a way to simply make this plot and would greatly appreciate help.

Comment: I would provide some data, or use the mtcars dataset. For more info, take a look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). The better the question is, the faster and more precise the answer will be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A straight-forward google search yields fairly good results:

http://www.r-bloggers.com/visual-interpretation-of-interaction-terms-in-linear-models-with-ggplot-rstats/

[Interaction Plot in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7323246/interaction-plot-in-ggplot2)

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/9477/how-to-draw-an-interaction-plot-with-confidence-intervals

http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Plotting_means_and_error_bars_(ggplot2)/#error-bars-for-within-subjects-variables